# IDE bug fixed in VS 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, async-await

This appears to be an IDE bug specific to VB in VS 2013. The following code produces a compiler warning:

[image]

> The Task returned from this Async Function will be dropped, and any exceptions in it ignored. Consider changing it to an Async Sub so its exceptions are propagated.

Well, clearly it already *is* an `Async Sub` (`void` in C#). While the general rule is to avoid `Async Sub`s, it's perfectly acceptable—and even advised—to do so with top-level event handlers such as this.

That's why I'm calling this an IDE bug. It only manifests when we set an event handler in VB (using either `AddHandler` or the `Handles` keyword). I'm not finding other reports of it, which frankly is odd... I can't imagine I'm the only one seeing it.

But to the question: can anyone report whether this nuisance has been fixed in VS 2015? If it has, I'll have further justification for upgrading sooner rather than later. (I have other reasons holding me back for the time being that aren't appropriate for discussion here.)

Comment: FYI this also happens in VB 2012 (with Option Strict Off, otherwise the warning is masked by an error).

Comment: @Basic: The error with `Option Strict On` is: *Option Strict On does not allow narrowing in implicit type conversions between method 'Private Async Sub cmdStart_Click(Sender As System.Windows.Controls.Button, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)' and delegate 'Delegate Sub RoutedEventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)'.*

Comment: Yes, that is the source of the problem (apparently the implicit conversion adds a layer with a `function`). Change the handler's signature to match the event signature (`sender As Object`), this fixes the warning.

Comment: @GSerg: That's it then. Thank you. My habit of changing the event signature to match the incoming type is what's causing it. When I relax it back to `Object` the warning goes away. Who'da thunk it? Care to enter it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I would first like to understand why it is so.

Comment: @GSerg: Very well; I would also. But please do come back and enter it as an answer when you can. This has been bothering me for a long time and you've been a source of relief. I'd like to properly thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the problem is a [relaxed delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531336.aspx) without an implicit widening conversion.

The `Click` event accepts an `Object` as the first parameter, but the handler accepts `Button` which makes it a relaxed delegate.
Because the handler's signature is more restrictive than the event signature, the code as is will only compile with `Option Strict Off`, and generate the seemingly spurious warning about a dropped async task.
Note that the problem does not occur when a widening conversion exists (e.g. where the event has `Button` and the handler has `Object`).

To fix the problem, you can:

- Change the handler's signature to match the event signature exactly:

  ```
  Private Async Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
  ```
- Wrap the `AddressOf` into a delegate constructor:

  ```
  AddHandler cmdStart.Click, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf cmdStart_Click)
  ```
- Ditch the `AddressOf` and wrap the call to the handler into a lambda:

  ```
  AddHandler cmdStart.Click, Sub(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
                                 Me.cmdStart_Click(sender, e)
                             End Sub
  ```

---

As for why this is happening and whose fault that is (yours, IDE's or the compiler's), I cannot tell you for sure.

However there is one thing I can see.
These two lines of code:

```
AddHandler cmdStart.Click, AddressOf RelaxedHandler

AddHandler cmdStart.Click, Sub(a0 As Object, a1 As EventArgs)
                               Me.RelaxedHandler(a0, a1)
                           End Sub
```

produce identical IL code, as far as the ILSpy is concerned:

```cs
this.cmdStart.Click += delegate(object a0, EventArgs a1)
{
    this.RelaxedHandler((Button)a0, a1);
}
;
this.cmdStart.Click += delegate(object a0, EventArgs a1)
{
    this.RelaxedHandler((Button)a0, a1);
}
;
```

but the first line generates a warning and the second line does not.

Comment: That works! Oddly, the compiler accepts `Sender As Button` in the lambda without generating the warning. Go figure.

Comment: As for the IL: 1. The compiler produces identical code, so it can't be that; 2. Nothing is my fault, ever; 3. The only thing left is the IDE.

Comment: Very, very nice piece of research and follow-up. Thank you.

Comment: FYI the warning no longer appears in VS 2015.3.